# Inversion of 2-variable functions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, fourier-transform

Suppose I have two two-variable functions, $A(x,y)$ and $B(u,v)$, whose relation is given by:

$\\$
$$B(u,v) = \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1} A(x,y) \cdot e^{-((x-u)^2+(y-v)^2)} \:\; dx dy$$
$\\$

In this case, given $A(x,y)$, I can readily calculate (compute) $B(u,v)$ by performing the double-integral above.

Now if I'm given only $B(u,v)$, would that be a way to 'invert' the double-integral so I can recover $A(x,y)$ ?

*ps: I stumbled upon this during my studies of the Radon/Fourier transforms, while trying to understand their inversion methods.*

Comment: $$ \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1} A(x,y) \cdot e^{-(x^2+y^2)} \:\; dx dy=Constant$$

Comment: @L.B. As the question is written, the right hand side of the equation for $B(x, y)$ doesn't depend on $x$ and $y$ since they're integrated out (so it's a constant.) Probably the integration variables should be something like $u$ and $v$ and there should be an $x$ and $y$ somewhere else in the integrand?

Comment: @Mr.G you're right. The functions $A$ and $B$ live on different spectrum (like Fourier Transform is in frequency domain while its inverse is on time domain). I'll correct the question. Thanks!

Comment: @L.B. It sort of looks like a 2D version of the [Weierstrass transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform). The problem is the limits are different. It might also be worth looking through [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform#Table_of_transforms) to see if any might be equivalent with the appropriate change of variables...

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D10902%26context%3Drtd&ved=2ahUKEwj0vauJupbjAhXSgeYKHehoB0YQFjAKegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw2AIMck9StckAZVRp86nrV4 You can find your answer from one of above links
( Sorry for such an answer neither do I have enough reputation to comment nor do I know how to use math text , so my sincere apologies)